# VSCode can not import external libraries

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, importerror, java-11

I am currently trying to learn the VSCode. I am programming in Java 11 now with VSCode. In the example code below, there are 4 lines of imports. First two of them are working. But the next two of them are giving the following errors.

```
package app;

import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import com.google.common.primitives.Ints;
import org.apache.commons.collections.iterators.ArrayIterator;

/**
 * Board_Space
 */
public class Board_Space {


}
```

```
"The import com.google cannot be resolved. Java(268435846) [5,8]"
"The import org.apache.commons.collections cannot be resolved. Java(268435846) [6,8]"
```

**How can I solve this errors and how can I use any kind of external libraries?**

```
Related Environment Info:

 - OS: Windows 10
 - JDK 11 is installed. JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables are set.
 - apache-maven-3.6.1 is installed. MAVEN_HOME and M2_HOME environment variables are set.
 - VSCode Version: 1.36.1 (user setup) 
 - VSCode Commit: 2213894ea0415ee8c85c5eea0d0ff81ecc191529


Extensions:

 - Name: Checkstyle for Java / Id: shengchen.vscode-checkstyle
 - Name: Code Spell Checker / Id: streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker
 - name: Debugger for Java / Id: vscjava.vscode-java-debug
 - Name: Java Dependency Viewer / Id: vscjava.vscode-java-dependency
 - Name: Java Extension Pack / Id: vscjava.vscode-java-pack
 - Name: Java Test Runner / Id: vscjava.vscode-java-test
 - Name: Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat / Id: redhat.java
 - Name: Maven for Java / Id: vscjava.vscode-maven
 - Name: Visual Studio IntelliCode / Id: visualstudioexptteam.vscodeintellicode
```

Answer (score 5):

adding external Jar files whithout maven or gradle `.classpath` file must be changed for the library.

1.create a folder named `lib` inside your project and add your `.jar` file into it

2.Configure paths in the `.classpath` like:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/xxxx.jar"/>
```

3.if it still thow error,Clean the workspace directory:`F1` - input `Clean` -`clean workspace`

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

global:

settings->
Java › Project: Referenced Libraries
in settings.json add:

```
"java.project.referencedLibraries": [

    "/usr/local/lib/**.jar"
]
```

local:

at ./.vscode/settings.json, add:

```
    "pathtojar/**.jar"
]
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30MHf.png)